# Refresh current page in PHP

Tags: php, web, refresh

Ok I have a page called *inbox.php* which is an inbox in receiving messages from other users. The new messages will load though every time the user "refreshes" the page. How can I write this in PHP where the *inbox.php* will automatically refreshes itself every 5 seconds? Thanks and peace.

Comment: it is not a php issue

Comment: Ok so can I use html instead? If yes, how.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with one simple `meta tag`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; ,URL=http://www.example.com/index.php">
                                    ^== seconds         ^=== URL
```

Comment: where will I put this?

Comment: inside the `<head></head>` tag

Comment: tnx man been looking for this

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the page every interval by placing this code before html code..

```
 $urlRefresh = "thispage.php";
 header("Refresh: 5; URL=\"" . $urlRefresh . "\""); // redirect in 5 seconds
```

But this is better I think to do with javascript insteed..

[link for tutorial](http://v2.scriptplayground.com/tutorials/php/Refresh-Page-Automatically)

Comment: BTW.. can I use header("Refresh: 5; URL = '$urlRefresh' "); instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should use client side scripting to do this. Easiest is in javascript. For example in your body tag:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(window.location.reload,5000);">
```

But you might want to reconsider refreshing the entire page each time. Consider loading just the changes with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one approach to this task:

1. The better and more efficient being AJAX, so that only the data part gets updated, and rest of the page stays same. check the below link for more details
   [AJAX reload every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125763/ajax-reload-every-10-seconds)
2. META tag in your HTML page
3. Javascript:

   reloadTimer(function(){
      window.location.reload(1);
   }, 5000);//using micro seconds

Check the below link

[How to reload page every 5 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second)